# How to load javascript/jquery on the component load when the external javascript files is imported in the index.html in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have all my external js and css files in public folder in the react app, and i am using them in the index.html file, Now when i render any component in , only the component gets loaded but the script associated with it not loaded, as the index.html file is not loaded.
so how can i load my scripts for the component when it gets render for the first time
I am using react-router-dom for navigation.

```
  <script src="js/donutscript.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/table.js"></script>
```

these are the scripts i am using in the index.html file